# how to skip Windows smart screen error while running python executable?

Tags: windows, cx-freeze, python-3.6, smartscreen

I am new to python. I managed to write my code for logging versions and generated executable using cx_freeze. It is working fine in my machine, but when I take it to other machines, I'm getting Windows smart screen error. 
Any idea how to get rid of this?
Quick help required.

Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzlPq.png)

Answer (score 0):

That is how SmartScreen works, it blocks "unpopular" executables. Depending on the system configuration the user might be able to click on "More Info" and run it anyway.

If enough people download and run your .exe then the SmartScreen block will go away. Microsoft does not specify how many downloads are required in their [FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20120202174001/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/SmartScreen-Filter-frequently-asked-questions-IE9):

> When you download a program from the Internet, SmartScreen Filter will check the program against a list of programs that are downloaded by a significant number of other Internet Explorer users and a list of programs that are known to be unsafe. If the program you're downloading isn't on either list, SmartScreen Filter will display a warning that the file isn't "commonly downloaded."

---

> SmartScreen checks files that you download from the web against a list of reported malicious software sites and programs known to be unsafe. If it finds a match, SmartScreen will warn you that the download has been blocked for your safety. [SmartScreen also checks the files that you download against a list of files that are well known](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17443/windows-internet-explorer-smartscreen-filter-faq) and downloaded by many people who use Internet Explorer. If the file that you're downloading isn't on that list, SmartScreen will warn you.

[Microsoft SmartScreen & Extended Validation (EV) Code Signing Certificates](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2012/08/14/microsoft-smartscreen-extended-validation-ev-code-signing-certificates/):

> Code signing is important
>   to our reputation intelligence because this higher level identity allows us to build
>   reputation across multiple programs signed by a publisher. It is also important
>   for publishers because signed programs inherit the reputation of the certificate
>   with which they are signed; this means every program a publisher distributes doesn’t
>   need to build reputation individually.

...

> Programs signed by an EV code signing certificate can immediately establish reputation
>   with SmartScreen reputation services even if no prior reputation exists for that
>   file or publisher.

---

Removing the "[Mark of the Web](https://textslashplain.com/2016/04/04/downloads-and-the-mark-of-the-web/)" by unblocking it in the files properties should also prevent the SmartScreen message.