# How can I set Details for an exe by using auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe

I am trying to generate an .exe using `auto-py-to-exe`. When I start the application, the following Windows message appears:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t0tg.jpg

Do I have to specify the publisher to avoid the message?
If so, which parameter do I have to specify?

Here is my current command:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --icon "C:/Users/Test/Downloads/Icon.ico" --uac-admin  "C:/Users/Test/PycharmProjects/SETUP.py"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218894/how-to-skip-windows-smart-screen-error-while-running-python-executable

Comment: Yes, thank you very much and sorry for the late reply.